# Interesting uses of fluent interfaces?

Tags: language-agnostic, fluent-interface

I am wondering where and when [fluent interfaces](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) are a good idea, so I am looking for examples. So far I have found only 3 useful cases, e.g. Ruby's collections, like

```
unique_words = File.read("words.txt").downcase.split.sort.uniq.length
```

and [Fest](http://code.google.com/p/fest/) (Java) for unit testing:

```
assertThat(yoda).isInstanceOf(Jedi.class)
    .isEqualTo(foundJedi)
    .isNotEqualTo(foundSith);
```

and [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/). Do you know of any other good examples that use a fluent interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/). :)

Comment: My Dog! jQuery IS always the answer!

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(VS.71).aspx
Or

Answer (score 0):

[RSpec](http://rspec.info/).   Example from the home page:

```
# bowling_spec.rb
require 'bowling'

describe Bowling do
  before(:each) do
    @bowling = Bowling.new
  end

  it "should score 0 for gutter game" do
    20.times { @bowling.hit(0) }
    @bowling.score.should == 0
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ninject: http://www.ninject.org
2. For an example that doesn't come from general-purpose libraries, I built an automated regression suite for a configuration wizard. I created a state machine that fills in values on a wizard page, verifies those values are acceptable, then moves on to the next page. The code for each step in the state machine looks like:

   step.Filler().Fill().Verify().GoForward();